# Find if String can be a sub sequence in another string

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

This question is a variation of Longest common sub-sequence which I was asked in a recent coding competition. It is not about finding the longest common sub sequence.

Consider a larger string s1 = `abaabbabcacc` and a smaller string s2 = `abc`. The power of a string is defined as repetition of each character of that string. So:

- s2 to power 1 is "abc"
- s2 to power 2 is "aabbcc"
- s3 to power 3 is "aaabbbccc" etc.

Now the question asked is as follows: How can we find the largest power of a string **s2** such that it was a valid sub-sequence in **s1**. So in this case answer is 3 because:

```
s2 to power 3 = "aaabbbccc"
s1 = "(a)b(aabb)a(bc)a(cc)"
```

The brute force algorithm seems straightforward: You start which power 1 and check if s2 to power 1 is sub-sequence of s1. You repeat until maximum power k to get time complexity of O(kn).

A better approach would be to first find the largest power k possible and then do binary search to find the required output. This would work in O(n*log(k)). So I was wondering if there is any method of doing this is O(n).

We can assume there are no memory constraints.

Comment: TTBOMK you *can't* "repeat till maximum power k to get time complexity of O(kn)", because no-one knows a general O(n)-time algorithm to determine whether one sequence is a subsequence of another.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, in this problem we have to check if complete string s2 can be a sub sequence in s1 which can be very easily done in O(n). We don't have to find longest common sub sequence.

Comment: Could you describe this very easy algorithm?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think this can be done with a greedy approach: if you find a character of a big string that matches the current character in the small string, take it, and move on.

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight, it's obvious now!  Suppose s2 is a subsequence of s1, then there is some way of pairing each character s2[i] with an equal character s1[matchFor[i]] so that they don't "cross", i.e., i > j => matchFor[i] > matchFor[j].  Take any valid solution and modify matchFor[1] to be the position of the *first* occurrence of s2[1] in s1 (as greedy does) -- this must still be a valid solution, since there are no obstacles further to the left. The values matchFor[i] for i >= 2 can be found by optimally solving the subproblem of s1[matchFor[1]+1..m] vs s2[2..n] (in the same way).